# What's the most compact and elegant way of checking whether an attribute is nil and/or zero? (note: rails 2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

In Rails 2, I have this line of code:

```
no_position = (image.nil? || !defined?(image.position) || image.position == 0)
```

This means that "no_position" is true if ANY of the following are true: (1) 'image' is not defined, or (2) 'image' is defined but its 'position' attribute is not, or (3) 'image' is defined and it has an attribute 'position' but that attribute's value is zero.

Basically, if there is no "image.position" with a non-zero value, "no_position" is true.

Is there a more elegant way of doing this, or is this as simple as I can get it?

Comment: I think short-circuit is fastest evaluation... and your order of evaluation is also in correct order..

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the value to an integer via `to_i`.

```
> nil.to_i
=> 0

> 0.to_i
=> 0

> '0'.to_i
=> 0
```

Combine with some `&&` to ensure both `image` and `image.position` exist and your code could be as simple as:

```
no_position = (image && image.position).to_i == 0
# or 
no_position = (image && image.position).to_i.zero?
```

---

But also depends on what all the possible inputs are. If it's `nil` or a number, or a string with a number it, you should be good. If there are no restriction on the input, you may have some problems.

```
> true.to_i
=> NoMethodError: undefined method `to_i' for true:TrueClass
```

---

Lastly, what you have isn't bad, as it is sort of a complicated check. we can just clean up your approach. And as a first step, frame it in the positive as that seems easier for most people to grasp. Then use `&&` to chain the conditions.

```
has_position = image && image.position && image.position == 0
# or
no_position = !( image && image.position && image.position == 0 )
```

Which is pretty clear, and has little to no tricksy-ness.

Comment: At least in my version of Rails (and I'm using an older version, not the most updated one), that doesn't solve the problem of what happens when image exists but doesn't have the attribute 'position.'

Comment: See my edit. In short `(image && image.position).to_i`

Comment: Added another edit at the end, which I think is actually what you want :)